# Why does the regex pattern not match the code?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Do you have any idea why this regex does not match the code below?

```
$regex = "!<title>(.*?)</title>!i";
```

code:

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
<title>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.homepageUrl == data:blog.url'>
        <data:blog.title/>
    <b:else/>
        <data:blog.pageName/> &raquo; <data:blog.title/>
    </b:if>
</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions to parse XML.

Your expression doesn't work because the dot doesn't match new lines. Adding the [DOTALL](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier `/.../s` would fix that, but then you'll have other problems like matching greedily instead of lazy.

Using an XML parser would be a better idea.

Comment: Is `b:include` a valid HTML tag?

Comment: Thanks Mark, this solved my problem! It is a blogger template, that needs to be parsed and served to download.

Comment: @hakre: Is this an HTML5 document fragment in the XML namespace?

Comment: Most certainly not ;) However I think my conclusion is wrong as well. Even if it would be in the XML namespace, it would be invalid HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for a correct regex:

```
(?<=<title>)(.*)(?=</title>)
```

Comment: I did try it! Posting without testing is not my jobs!